# object array having old values even after making it empty in angular

Tags: javascript, angular9

I have a component that acts as a widget for another component to show multiple images whether from server or local blob. I'm sending server images as input to widget component. Then I've declared `combArr = []` which includes server and local images and being used for ngfor loop. I have a hidden input tag to select local files. Initially, the array combArr is empty. Issue is when I select local file in the `change` event, I'm printing combArr array before and after reading the file. It shows the same local image both before and after print. And in html the combArr does not updates. When a file is selected `handleFileSelect()` is called. In this method, I consoled combArr twice (see image). One before file reading (line no 136) and one after (line no 154). Both show the same values. 1st is the server image which displays but the 2nd blob does not reflect in UI. And how can the blob be printing before reading file? Can anyone help me with these 2 issues?
[image]

```css
export class MultiFileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() serverImages: any[] = []; //coming from api at the time of Edit PHR
  @Input() isSingleImage?: boolean = false; //this variable for single image upload

  combArr = [];

  ngOnChanges() {
    // serverImages: from dict response
    this.combArr = [];
    
    console.log(this.combArr)
    this.serverImages.map(x => {
      let carr = {
        prevSrc: x.url,
        thumbSrc: this.getThumb(x, 'server'),
        upFile: null,
        fileName: x.title,
        iconSrc: this.getIcon(x, 'server'),
        type: this.getType(x, 'server'),
        status: 'server'
      }
      this.combArr.push(carr)
    });
    console.log(this.serverImages.length)
    console.log(this.combArr)
  }

  // Opens actionsheet to choose from Camera/Gallery
  async openDialog() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: "Select Attachments",
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Camera',
        icon: 'camera',
        handler: () => {
          // console.log('Camera clicked');
          // this.openCamera();
          actionSheet.dismiss();
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Gallery',
        icon: 'folder-open',
        handler: () => {
          // console.log('Gallery clicked');
          this.openGallery();
          actionSheet.dismiss();
        },

      }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
        },
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

  // In web: Opens popup to select file. 
  // In iOS & Android: pending
  openGallery() {
    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('file-input') as HTMLElement;
    element.click();
  }

  // this method is called when a file is selected
  handleFileSelect(event) {
    console.log('SAM: event: ', event)
    console.log(this.combArr)
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const filesArr: File = event.target.files;
      const filesLength = event.target.files.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (evt: any) => {
          console.log('SAM: evt:', evt);
          let carr = {
            prevSrc: evt.target.result,
            thumbSrc: this.getThumb(filesArr[i], 'local'),
            upFile: filesArr[0],
            fileName: filesArr[0].name,
            iconSrc: this.getIcon(filesArr[i], 'local'),
            type: this.getType(filesArr[i], 'local'),
            status: 'local'
          }
          this.combArr.push(carr)
          console.log(this.combArr)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  // Gets the thumb image 
  getThumb(item: any, status: string) {
    if (status == 'server') {
      if (item?.contentType?.includes('image')) {
        return this.imgThumbnail;
      } else if (item?.contentType == 'application/pdf') {
        return this.pdfThumbnail;
      } else if (item?.contentType == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || item?.contentType == 'application/msword') {
        return this.docThumbnail;
      }
    } else if (status == 'local') {
      if (item?.type == 'image/jpeg' || item?.type == 'image/png' || item?.type == 'image/gif') {
        return this.imgThumbnail;
      } else if (item?.type == 'application/pdf') {
        return this.pdfThumbnail;
      } else if (item?.type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || item?.type == 'application/msword') {
        return this.docThumbnail;
      }
    }
  }

  // Gets the type of file either in server or local files
  getType(item: any, status: string) {
    if (status == 'server') {
      if (item?.contentType?.includes('image')) {
        return 'image';
      } else if (item?.contentType == 'application/pdf') {
        return 'pdf';
      } else if (item?.contentType == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || item?.contentType == 'application/msword') {
        return 'doc';
      }
    } else if (status == 'local') {
      if (item?.type == 'image/jpeg' || item?.type == 'image/png' || item?.type == 'image/gif') {
        return 'image';
      } else if (item?.type == 'application/pdf') {
        return 'pdf';
      } else if (item?.type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || item?.type == 'application/msword') {
        return 'doc';
      }
    }
  }

  // Gets the icon for lower left img tag. Its either zoom or download icon
  getIcon(item: any, status: string) {
    if (status == 'server') {
      if (item?.contentType?.includes('image')) {
        return this.zoomIcon;
      } else if (item?.contentType == 'application/pdf') {
        return this.zoomIcon;
      } else if (item?.contentType == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || item?.contentType == 'application/msword') {
        return this.downloadIcon;
      }
    } else if (status == 'local') {
      if (item?.type == 'image/jpeg' || item?.type == 'image/png' || item?.type == 'image/gif') {
        return this.zoomIcon;
      } else if (item?.type == 'application/pdf') {
        return this.zoomIcon;
      } else if (item?.type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || item?.type == 'application/msword') {
        return this.downloadIcon;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <img class="first" src="/assets/images/doc-pat/phr/_ic_attachment.png" alt="">
    <ion-label style="color:black;display: initial;"> {{attachment_label}}({{combArr.length}})</ion-label>
    <input  #fileInput (click)="fileInput.value = null" style="display: none" id="file-input" multiple type="file" accept="image/*, application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of combArr; let i = index">
      <img  class="pdf-img" [src]="item.thumbSrc">
      <div class="lower-portion">
        <div>
          <img style="cursor:pointer"  class="first" [src]="item.iconSrc" alt="" (click)="clickAction(i)">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img style="cursor:pointer" class="second" [src]="delIcon" alt="" (click)="clickDelete(i)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="isSingleImage && combArr.length > 0" class="item">
      <img  class="pdf-img" [src]='blankThumbnail'>
      <div class="lower-portion-add-button" (click)="openDialog()">
        <div>
          <ion-icon class="first" id="selectfile" name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the way you are using the FileReader is, as we say, "out of Angular's world", or "not the Angular way", so Angular isn't "aware" of it.

Normally, `document.getElementById` has nothing to do in an Angular app, but there are cases where we don't really have a choice, like this one, I guess.

There's a workaround/hack to kind of "shake up" Angular and force it to refresh and be made aware of changes that were made out of its world, by using Zone.js :

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public zone: NgZone){  }

someMethod() {
    this.serverImages.forEach(x => { // forEach! Not map()
      let carr = {
        prevSrc: x.url,
        thumbSrc: this.getThumb(x, 'server'),
      };
      this.combArr.push(carr);
    });
      // now your combArr has been modified, force Angular to re-render :

    this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log("re-rendered!")
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. What should I write in ngZone.run method to re-render it?

Comment: Well... this. What I wrote. You can even omit the `console.log` entirely. The important thing is `zone.run()`, but it requires a callback function, even if it's empty.

Comment: Actually what I think the issue was input tag not clearing previously selected files. So after reading the file, I cleared the input tag using ViewChild. This solved my problem. I think.

Comment: I checked my final code again even after clearing input tag it didn't worked. I tried NgZone also but did not worked. The problem is in `handleFileSelect()` method. On entering this method, combArr is printing blob file without reading any file.